# stereo depth map but with a single moving camera measured with sensors

Tags: computer-vision

I've just gotten started learning about calculating depth from stereo images and before I went and committed to learning about this I wanted to check if it was a viable choice for a project I'm doing. I have a drone with a single rgb camera that has sensors that can give the orientation and movement of the drone. Would it be possible to sample two frames, the distance, and orientation differences between the samples and use this to calculate depth? I've seen in most examples the cameras are lined up horizontally. Is this necessary for stereo images or can I use any reasonable angle and distance between the two sampled images? Would it be feasible to do this in real time? My overall goal is to do some sort of monocular slam to have this drone navigate indoor areas. I know that ORB slam exists but I am mostly doing this for a learning experience and so would like to do things from scratch where possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is doable. Stereo cameras are set up horizontally for ease-of-use (it simplifies some things), but it's not necessary for the calculation. Especially if you know the relative change in position and orientation of your camera for each picture then there are equations to do this. There are lots of implementations of monocular slam so it's not an impossible problem, though doing it yourself from scratch will depend on you. If realtime is a concern, it'd probably be best to use the onboard computer to just send data to a stronger, stationary one nearby to do the calculations.